# MongoDB aggregate query: $size count item only if equal to certain value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I know how to write a query such that I can count the number of items in an array per document using `$size`.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   {project : {"name" : 1, _id:0, sizeOf : {$size : "$People.Age"}}}
)
```

How do I write a query using `$size`, but I only want to count the field if it equals a certain value (for example `People.Ages.Current_Age : 21`). I'm assuming I'd use `$eq` for that?

Sample Code:

```
{
    "People" : [
        {
            "Name" : "Jen",
            "Ages" : {
                "Current_Age" : 32,
                "Graduate_Age" : 26,
            }
        },
        {
            "Name" : "Bill",
            "Ages" : {
                "Current_Age" : 30,
                "Graduate_Age" : 22,
            }
        },
        {
            "Name" : "Josh",
            "Ages" : {
                "Current_Age" : 27,
                "Graduate_Age" : 24,
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1, "_id": 0,
    "sizeOf": {
      "$size": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$People",
          "as": "people",
          "cond": { "$eq": ["$$people.Ages.Current_Age", 21] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the dollar sign when used for "$People" and "$$people.age", I understand why it is used for operators but not other things.

Comment: `$` represents the document fields and the `$$` represents the [`let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) variables which we assume in the query.

Comment: Here in the above query. We have taken your `$People` documents array as input parameter of the `$filter` and taken `$$people` as let variable which contains single element from the array. It is same as javascript filter. Something like `People.filter((people) => people.age === 21)`

Comment: So what if Age (call it ages) is an object itself that has a single element in it that I want to access? For example I want to access People.Ages.CurrentAge. How would that change the above code? If I want CurrentAge = 21.

Comment: @JamesMitchell You should post some sample document. And if your people ages is object then you cannot use `$filter` here. It can only be used with the arrays

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter operator here, filter the array before taking size.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {project : {"name" : 1, _id:0, sizeOf : {$size : {
        $filter: {
            input: "$People.Age",
            as: "age",
            cond: { $eq:[$$age, 21] }
        }
    }}}}
)
```

Comment: I'm getting $$age is not defined (same if I make it $age)

Comment: Can you add an example document with the question.